# Having an issue with meter conversion to feet and inches in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My program converts feet and inches to meters just fine, but it will always add a random amount of feet on the meter to feet and inches conversion. I can not figure out why. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
EX) it states that 1.3208026m is equal to 8ft 4in when it is actually 4ft 4in.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int feet;
double meters, inches;

int main()
{

        cout << "Enter feet " << endl;
        cin >> feet;
        cout << "Enter inches " << endl;
        cin >> inches;

        inches = feet * 12 + inches;
        meters = inches / 39.370;

        cout << setprecision(8) << meters << "m" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Enter meters. " << endl;
        cin >> meters;
        inches = meters * 39.37;
        while (inches > 12)
        {
            if (inches > 12)
                inches = inches - 12;
            feet++;

        }

    cout << feet << " ft and " << setprecision(8) << inches << "in" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edit your question to add the code, select it and then click the {} button to tell the editor it's code.  I suspect a precision issue anyway.

Comment: Look again at your while/if loop, specifically, it's scope:(

Comment: If you had stepped through with your debugger, youi would have seen 'feet' getting incremented whether or not 'inches>12' :(

Comment: My programming teacher has not even began to describe how to use the debugger. He always insists that we run without debugging; so checking the debugger wasn't even on my mind. I will do that from now on before I post. Thanks for the tip on that.

Comment: @J_Ray93 And, what's stopping you, from learning how to use one, yourself? No teacher taught me how to use a debugger, but learning how to use it, improved the bug-fixing part of code writing, tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset feet back to zero after the first conversion.

Comment: This worked for me, I reset all variables to zero and reran the program  with several different numbers and they all came out correctly. Thank you so much!

Comment: The issue others have commented on regarding the while loop is not solved with braces, or even by removing the if.  Entering certain values can give wrong results, for example entering 0.30480060 metres comes out at 0 ft and 12 in, instead of 1 ft and 0 in.  The way to solve this is to use an integer variable for the number of inches in the second part of the program (metres to feet and inches), and to change the while condition to `inches >= 12`.  The if condition is an unnecessary duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (inches > 12)
        inches = inches - 12;
    feet++;
```

No.  Needs braces, else your feet will fail you.

Comment: It has braces, on the lines above and below; or do they need to be on the same line as the start and end lines?